# TinyXML2 C++ Import

Tags: c++, import, wxwidgets, tinyxml2

I've got a XML File looking like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Table>
   <Dataset>
      <Year>Year1</Year>
      <Month>Month1</Month>
      <Day>Day1</Day>
   </Dataset>
   <Dataset>
      <Year>Year2</Year>
      <Month>Month2</Month>
      <Day>Day1</Day>
   </Dataset>
</Table>
```

And I want to read this file with C++. My code looks like:

```
XMLElement* xeTable = xeExport->FirstChildElement("Table");
     XMLElement* xeDataset = xeTable->FirstChildElement("Dataset");
         XMLElement* xeYear = xeDataset->FirstChildElement("Year");
         XMLElement* xeMonth = xeDataset->FirstChildElement("Month");
         XMLElement* xeDay = xeDataset->FirstChildElement("Day");

             XMLText* xnYear  = xeYear->FirstChild()->ToText();
             const char* cYear = xnYear->Value();

             XMLText* xnMonth  = xeMonth->FirstChild()->ToText();
             const char* cMonth = xnMonth->Value();

             XMLText* xnDay  = xeDay->FirstChild()->ToText();
             const char* cDay = xnDay->Value();
```

It reads year, month and date of first dataset. What to do know, for reading data of next dataset? I superiored to delete the first dataset after reading so I can read the second dataset again with FirstChildElement();. But I didn't get it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Am not sure if your issue is solved or not. Just wonder if encoding="UTF-16" not causing any problem? Is tinyXML support UTF-16?

Answer (score 1):

```
xeDataset = xeDataset->NextSiblingElement("Dataset")
```

to elaborate:

```
XMLElement* xeTable = xeExport->FirstChildElement("Table");

for(XMLElement* xeDataset = xeTable->FirstChildElement("Dataset"); xeDataset; xeDataset = xeDataset->NextSiblingElement("Dataset"))
{
         XMLElement* xeYear = xeDataset->FirstChildElement("Year");
         XMLElement* xeMonth = xeDataset->FirstChildElement("Month");
         XMLElement* xeDay = xeDataset->FirstChildElement("Day");

         XMLText* xnYear  = xeYear->FirstChild()->ToText();
         const char* cYear = xnYear->Value();

         XMLText* xnMonth  = xeMonth->FirstChild()->ToText();
         const char* cMonth = xnMonth->Value();

         XMLText* xnDay  = xeDay->FirstChild()->ToText();
         const char* cDay = xnDay->Value(); 
}
```

Comment: The XML file is encoded in UTF-16 format. Will it work with TinyXML 1/2? Their documentation said they support UTF-8 but said nothing about UTF-16.

Comment: @someone_smiley That really sounds like a distinct question unrelated to this answer.

Comment: @someone_smiley The tinyxml codebase is pretty small (hence tiny); I had a very quick look and there are no typedefs for wchar_t type, just char so it suggests utf8 only.